# Testcafe throws an error invalid arg type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to write some basic e2e tests with `testcafe` on a `React/Electron` app. First I wrote a basic test getting the app Page Title:

**App.e2e.js**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Electron App`.page('../../app/app.html');

test('should contain expected page title', async browser => {
  await browser.expect(getPageTitle()).eql('Electron App');
});
```

The aboove test, **it worked well!**

But now I'm trying to add other tests like trying to login into the app with the next example:

**App.e2e.js**

```
import { Selector, Role } from 'testcafe';

const UserRole = Role('../../app/app.html', async t => {
  await t
    .typeText('input[name="email"]', 'user@user.com')
    .typeText('input[name="password"]', 'secret')
    .click(Selector('button[type=submit]').withText('Login'));
});

fixture`Electron App`
  .page('../../app/app.html')
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t.useRole(UserRole);
  });

test('Click a doc', async t => {
  await t
    .click(Selector('span').withText('Document'))
    .expect(Selector('h1').withText('Document').exists)
    .ok();
});
```

When I try to run `e2e` tests, I get a weird error like this:

**Console output**

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at resolveFileUrl (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\api\test-page-url.js:20:30)
    at Object.resolvePageUrl (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\api\test-page-url.js:42:16)
    at Proxy.createRole (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\role\index.js:73:17)
    at Role (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\api\exportable-lib\index.js:15:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\tests\e2e\App.e2e.js:8:18)
    at Function._execAsModule (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\compiler\test-file\api-based.js:50:13)
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler._runCompiledCode (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\compiler\test-file\api-based.js:150:42)
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler.execute (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\compiler\test-file\api-based.js:174:21)
    at ESNextTestFileCompiler.compile (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\compiler\test-file\api-based.js:180:21)
    at Compiler._getTests (C:\Users\user\Git\electronApp\node_modules\testcafe\src\compiler\index.js:86:31)

Type "testcafe -h" for help.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

It seems like testcafe can't find the correct `path` to launch the electron app, but in the first case the test worked with the same path. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Relative URLs in Roles are not supported yet. Keep track of this issue: [Support relative urls in Roles](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3406). As a workaround, you can use an absolute path.